# Remove first object from json response @ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring

In my test application I have a controller with the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{city}", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public @ResponseBody
MyAnwser getAnwser(@PathVariable String city) {
    return new MyAnwser(city);
}
```

which returns the following

```
{"result":{"valueA":"valueB"}}
```

I'm looking for a way to remove the first object sign from the response - "{" to get:

```
"result":{"valueA":"valueB"}
```

but I can't figure out a way to do it while using @ResponseBody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do that, you wouldn't end up with a valid JSON! In other words, you <strike>can't</strike> mustn't do that.

Comment: no first and last character of string can be easily removed !

Comment: for removing first and last character of Received string see my answer ! if i am wrong please comment !

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be removed. I'm saying they mustn't be removed!

Answer (score 0):

As you want to Remove First And Last Character of your Received String Then use

```
String str="your Received String goes here";
str=str.substring(1, str.length()-1)
```

Comment: hehe, but how to do that in the context of spring and the returned bean? - that's the real question - how to integrate that...

Comment: @zibi i just answered the comment of Michael ! and also you can try by casting returned bean to string and then try my answer and test the result !